# PHP: select current option

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB table with all categories (id, category) and table with all of events (id, event, categoryID).

And on the event editing form I have the `select` field with all of the categories (getting from the DB). But sinse I'm developing an editing form, I need to select current category by default.

This is my select field (PHP method that gets all the categories from DB and puts them in the following order):

```
<option value="1">Cat1</option>
<option value="2">Cat2</option>
<option value="3">Cat3</option>
<option value="4">Cat4</option>
<option value="5">Cat5</option>
```

Let's say, current event is under category 3, so I need the following HTML to be generated:

```
<option value="1">Cat1</option>
<option value="2">Cat2</option>
<option value="3" selected>Cat3</option>
<option value="4">Cat4</option>
<option value="5">Cat5</option>
```

How do I achieve it with PHP, if I have the catID?

Hopefully, this question is clear enough. Sorry for my bad explanation

UPD: This is my PHP code that generates category list:

```
public function getCatList($conf) {
  $mysqli = $this->dbConnect($conf);

  // Quering...
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['category'] . '</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: show your current php code?

Comment: Done. Sorry for not adding it at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending to your `while` iteration a condition will solve this for you:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $isSelected = $row['id'] == $catID;
    echo '<option '.($isSelected ? 'selected="selected"' : '').' value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['category'] . '</option>';
}
```

You're making a comparison if the current value is the same as that stored in `$catID` - and store the boolean result in a variable. In the echo you're just doing a conditional forking and appending the `selected` attribute if the value was true, otherwise not appending any empty string.

Comment: Hm. This one seems better then mine

Comment: The general idea behind this approach is you want to minimize the mixing of your HTML and PHP. You want to perform all calculations before you do your printing/echoing, that way your output part will be much easier to understand (compared to putting it all in-line, of course this isn't a complex case, but imagine having multiple data attributes, condition switchers, etc).

Comment: Just because I find it weird: Why didn't you, @Gabor, coded `$isSelected = ($row['id'] == $catID) ? 'selected' : '';` and then on the echo just use `echo '<option '.$isSelected.' value="'...` ? (is it because something or just favouritism?)

Comment: @MoshMage: your proposed way of writing it is fine as well, I just went with this formality as there was only one condition however with a more complex case (as I started pointing out in my comment) would definitely benefit the readability by moving even the ternary operator over to the computation part (or better yet, implement a select template which can easily accomodate all sorts of modifiers without having to manually write them all out).

Comment: @Gabor Ah! I thought it was some unspoken rule or some methodology thingy; Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {3

  echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
  //if condition is met then make the option selected
  if($row['categoryID'] == 3) {
      echo " selected='selected' ";
  }
  echo '>' . $row['category'] . '</option>';

}
```

Comment: Oh, man. I've posted this question and found the solution (very similar to yours) by myself. I'm dumb... sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the selected catID as a parameter to your `getCatList`-function. Then just change the creation of your HTML to include the selected-attribute:

```
public function getCatList($conf, $catID = 0) {
  $mysqli = $this->dbConnect($conf);

  // Quering...
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"' . ($row['id']==$catID?' selected':'') . '>' . $row['category'] . '</option>';
  }
}
```

now you can just pass the catID to your function:

```
$myConf = "something";
$myCatID = 3;
getCatList($myConf, $myCatID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //query for the categories and options
 $current_value = 3;
 $total_num_of_options = mysql_num_rows($your_query_result);
 for($count = 1; $count <= $total_num_of_options){
   echo "<option value='".$count."' ";
   if($count == $current_value)
      echo "selected";
   echo ">cat".$count."</option>";
 }
```